# E ∩ K = F implies [EK : F] = [E : F][K : F]?

Tags: extension-field

I have come across a problem that shows E ∩ K = F  if [EK : F] = [E : F][K : F]. I wonder if the converse holds. I know this reduce to showing the the F-basis of E is a K-basis if E ∩ K = F (if this is true), but is stuck here. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to study the concept ot [linearly disjoint extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_disjoint). [Pete L. Clark's lecture notes](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/FieldTheory.pdf) give everything you want to know. [My "first aid" notes for a past study group](http://users.utu.fi/lahtonen/linearly_disjoint.pdf) may or may not help, depending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the degree $6$ extension $L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,e^{2\pi i/3})$ of $\Bbb Q$, the splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\Bbb Q$. Then $L=EF$
where $E=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ and $F=\Bbb Q(e^{2\pi i/3}\sqrt[3]2)$.
Both of these have degree $3$ and $E\cap F=\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks. But will it be true if we further require that [E : F], [K : F] coprime?

Comment: @assking In that case it's true.